# Screen flickers black & white repeatedly

Tags: java, image, swing, thread-sleep

Just wrote a program that displays dynamic animation. BTW, it runs but the problem is that backround keeps on flickering black and white at a rapid speed. i have googled it but didnt get an appropriate answer. Here is the code:
For main method -

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class nam2 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
             nam2 b= new nam2();
             b.run();
    }
        private Sprite sprite;              //class to control characteristics of image
        private Animation a;                //class to control animation  
        private ScreenManager s;            //class to control monitor screen
        private Image bg;                   //an image

        private static final DisplayMode modes1[] = {    // List of desired DisplayModes
            new DisplayMode(800,600,32,0),        
            new DisplayMode(800,600,25,0),
            new DisplayMode(800,600,16,0),
            new DisplayMode(640,480,32,0),
            new DisplayMode(640,480,24,0),
            new DisplayMode(1920,1080,16,0),
        };
        //load images and add scenes
        public void loadImages(){
            bg = new ImageIcon("G:\\bg2.jpg").getImage();
            Image face1 = new ImageIcon("G:\\naman1.jpg").getImage();
            Image face2 = new ImageIcon("G:\\3.jpg").getImage();

            a = new Animation();
            a.addScene(face1,500);
            a.addScene(face2,500);

            sprite = new Sprite(a);
            sprite.setVelocityX(0.3f);
            sprite.setVelocityY(0.3f);
        }
        //run method call from main method
        public void run(){
            s = new ScreenManager();
            try{
                DisplayMode dm = s.findFirstCompDisplayMode(modes1);
                s.setFullScreen(dm);
                loadImages();
                movieLoop();
            }finally{s.restoreScren();}


        }

        public void movieLoop(){
            long startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long cumTime = startingTime;

            while(cumTime - startingTime <10000){
                long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime ;
                cumTime += timePassed;
                update(timePassed); 
                //draw and update screen
                Graphics2D g = s.getGraphics();
                draw(g);
                g.dispose();
                s.update();

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(20);   
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }

       //draw method 
       public void draw(Graphics g){
            g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(sprite.getImage(),                 Math.round(sprite.getX()),Math.round(sprite.getY()),null);

          }
        //update method

        private void update(long timePassed) {
            if(sprite.getX() < 0 ){
                sprite.setVelocityX(Math.abs(sprite.getVelocityX()));
            }else if(sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth() >= s.getWidth()){
                sprite.setVelocityX(-Math.abs(sprite.getVelocityX()));
            }

            if(sprite.getY() < 0 ){
                sprite.setVelocityY(Math.abs(sprite.getVelocityY()));
            }else if(sprite.getY() + sprite.getHeight() >= s.getHeight()){
                sprite.setVelocityY(-Math.abs(sprite.getVelocityY()));
            }
            sprite.update(timePassed);
        }



    }
```

I have uploaded code of only main class . If other class codes are required please tell me. Isnt it something related to threads coz when i change the sleep time of thread, the speed of flickering changes. So my major issue to write this questions is:
Why does the screen flickers black to white and again to black continuously.

Comment: try creating a simple complete program that shows only your problem. The fewer code a reader has to process the more likely are good answers. Also, please do share your environment (Operating System, Java Version, etc.)

Comment: Ok let me try i will update my question soon.

Comment: Why does the screen flickers black to white and again to black continuously. -- (just guessing, reason incomplete code) 1. because is painted to JFrame, 2. because is painted by using getGraphics(for printing to Printer or File), 3. because is used prehistoric draw(), 4. because is locked by Thread.sleep(20);, 5. because Thread.sleep(20); is sets to very short delay

Comment: If you are drawing straight to the screen without buffering, that would explain the screen flicker. Draw onto an off image and then draw that to the screen. This may help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html

Comment: I have painted the image using buffered strategy.

Comment: I am guessing draw() is passed in the screen Graphics. If so, I would expect only 1 call to drawImage() to finally draw the buffered image onto screen.

Comment: how to make a call to buffered image

Comment: Guys I have just found that when i set bg image the image doesnt flick, only JFrame bg flick so can buffered strategy is useful for that.